# Add custom post meta to woocommerce order email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’m trying to add a custom product meta to my woocommerce new order notification e-mails.

The custom product meta field is as follows:

```
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'                => '_text_field', 
        'label'             => __( 'OUDE DBV Artikelnummer', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder'       => 'LET OP! Dit is het OUDE artikelnummer',
        'desc_tip'          => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'LET OP! Dit is het OUDE Dordtse Bazar Verhuur artikelnummer.', 'woocommerce' ) 
    )
);
```

I’ve copied the email-orders-details.php to my Child theme folder and the new column is showing perfectly fine in the email.

```
<tr>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'DBV Art. Nr.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
```

Now I’m struggling to retrieve the values of this custom field. I’ve copied the email-order-items.php to my child theme folder. I’ve added this code here, but no values are shown in the email. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// allow other plugins to add additional product information here.
        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

        ?>
        </td>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true ); ?> 
        </td>
```

Hope you can help me out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `$product->get_id()`.

```
// allow other plugins to add additional product information here.
do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

?>
</td>
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
    <?php echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_text_field', true ); ?> 
</td>
```

Comment: Great @Bhautik this solved my problem. This indeed was on product level instead of post level. Thanks!